# Como salvar o tamanho do meu recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

O tamanho do meu recyclerview e setado da seguntinte forma  `mDatabase.limitToFirst(valor1*valor2)`... `valor1 = 1 * valor= 4` = `4`

Quando eu rolo o recyclerview até o final chamo `EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener` que chama o contador `valor1++`
`valor1 = 2 * valor= 4` = `8` oque acontece é que a cada rolagem até o final aumenta  4 em 4.

o problema é quando passo para a próxima atividade(abro o conteúdo),
quando eu volto quero continuar com o mesmo tamanho...
eu não sei como salvar este resultado e recuperar-lo...
tentei savedInstance mais nunca usei antes então não deu certo...
putExtra não dá já que o click é feito na atividade do recyclerview... enfim agradeço a quem ajudar!

```
LoadData();

}
private void LoadData() {

    mDatabase.limitToFirst(valor1*valor2)
            .startAt(valor2)
            .orderByChild("number").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            questionList.clear();
            if(!dataSnapshot .hasChildren()){
                //currentPage--;
            }
            for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Blog blog = data.getValue(Blog.class);
                questionList.add(blog);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                String posicao = counter = getIntent().getExtras().getString("position");
                mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if(Load == false){
                    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(Integer.parseInt(posicao));
                    Load = true;
                }else{
                }

                Handler handle = new Handler();
                handle.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mRela.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }, 1000);

            }

        }


        @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    if(Load == false){
        recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
            final String posicao = counter = getIntent().getExtras().getString("position");
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Call smooth scroll
                Log.i("TESTEEEE",posicao);
                recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(Integer.parseInt(posicao));
                Load = true;
            }
        });}else{

    }}
@Override public void onStart() {
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(mLayoutManager) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view) {
            mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Handler handle = new Handler();
            handle.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    valor1++;
                    LoadData();}
            },2000);

        }
    });
    super.onStart();
}
```

```
   public class RecyclerViewBlog extends 
   RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewBlog.MyViewHolder> {

Context ctxt;
private List<Blog> mQuestLIst;
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    View View;
    TextView titu,desc,nome,data,carg,qntd,sobre;
    ImageView imag,imag1,imag2,imag3,imag4,imgp;


    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        View = view;
        ctxt = view.getContext();
        titu = view.findViewById(R.id.titu);
        desc = view.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        nome = view.findViewById(R.id.nome);
        data = view.findViewById(R.id.datt);
        carg = view.findViewById(R.id.carg);
        qntd = view.findViewById(R.id.qntd);
        imag = view.findViewById(R.id.imag0);
        sobre = view.findViewById(R.id.sobre);
        imgp = view.findViewById(R.id.imgp);
    }

    public void setFoto(AccessControlContext ctx, String foto) {
        Glide.with(imgp.getContext()).load(foto).centerCrop().bitmapTransform(new CircleTransform(imgp.getContext())).override(40,40).into(imgp);
    }
    public void setImag(AccessControlContext ctx, String imge) {
        Glide.with(imag.getContext()).load(imge).into(imag);
    }

    public void setData(String hora) {
        //if (data == null)return;
        data.setText(converteTimeStamp(hora));

    }
}

public RecyclerViewBlog(List<Blog> mQuestLIst){
    this.mQuestLIst = mQuestLIst;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.blog_row, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}int total=0;
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
   final Blog blog = mQuestLIst.get(position);


    holder.carg.setText(blog.getCarg());
    holder.desc.setText(blog.getDesc());
    //holder.data.setText(blog.getData());
    holder.nome.setText(blog.getNome());
    holder.titu.setText(blog.getTitu());
    holder.sobre.setText(blog.getSobre());
    holder.qntd.setText(blog.getVisitas().getVizualicacoes());
    holder.setData(blog.getData());
    holder.setFoto(getContext(), blog.getFoto());
    holder.setImag(getContext(), blog.getImag1());


    total+=mQuestLIst.get(position).getConta();

    if(position==mQuestLIst.size()-1)
    Log.i("RESULTADO_DA_CONTA", String.valueOf(total));
    holder.View.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent blogstart = new Intent (ctxt, EnterBlog.class);
            blogstart.putExtra("post", blog.getPost());
            blogstart.putExtra("blog", blog.getBlog());
            blogstart.putExtra("position",String.valueOf(position));
            ctxt.startActivity(blogstart);
        }
    });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount()  {
    return mQuestLIst.size();
}

private CharSequence converteTimeStamp(String milesssegundos){
    return DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(Long.parseLong(milesssegundos), System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
}
```

}

Comment: Explique melhor

Comment: se você olhar o `limitToFirst` é onde coloco a quantidade de itens a serem baixado do `DB` este valor aumenta conforme rolo para baixo... então quando eu passo para a próxima atividade e volto eu perco esta contagem...

Comment: O recyclerview regência isso ai. Você pode colocar a "lista completa"